# Is it possible to declare two variables For-Each Loop in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function which can check, If a two string has all characters with the same frequency. So in order to do that, I tried to make two Maps i.e `unordered_map<char, int>`. So in my next step, I just want to compare each value of each `char` on my map.

```
string A;
string B;

unordered_map<char, int> a;
unordered_map<char, int> b;

for (char i : A)
{
    a[i]++;
}
for (char i : B)
{
    b[i]++;
}
for (char i : A &&char j : B)
{
    //code goes here
}
```

So, Is it possible to have a For-Each loop with two different variable like that?

Comment: What is i and B?. Why do you need two maps?

Comment: check now I have edited the post

Comment: What is A and B in the last loop?

Comment: Probably not because the shortened for loop goes through the entire collection, and it does not allow for conditions. The collections could be of different sizes, thus resulting in out of bounds for one collection.

Comment: What semantics do you propose that `&&` have (i.e. what do you want it to mean)? (BTW for your problem you can sort the two strings and check if they are equal)

Comment: By saying '&&'  I mean to look for a char in A and a char in B. I want a solution in O(N) time.

Comment: are your maps the same size?

Comment: Yes, my maps are of the same size.

Comment: OK, See my answer than.

Comment: @ApurvJha *"By saying '&&' I mean to look for a char in A and a char in B."* -- what does this mean? Range-based for loops don't "look for" anything; they iterate over each element in the container. (Based on your goal, iterating over each element in `A` **or** `B` would seem to be appropriate, but that does not fit the choice of the `&&` symbol.) Perhaps you should replace `//code goes here` with the code that would "compare each value of each `char` on my map"? Your textual description is good enough that actual code might explain what you intend the loop to iterate over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is no, you can not do that. This for loop is called **for each loop**, and structure goes like this:

```
for each ELEMENT in MAP/ARRAY/VECTOR
    do something
```

If I am correct your intention is to have something like this

```
in loop 
  store each element of MAP_A into i and each element of MAP_B in j
```

It is not possible

Your only solution is:
NOTE: This is for arrays of the same size.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumOfElemens; ++i)
    int aa = a[i];
    int bb = b[i];
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

You can also shorthand this to:

```
for (int i = 0, aa = a[0], bb = b[0]; i < NumOfElemens; ++i, aa = a[i], bb = b[i]) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

This also might work, but I do not guaranty that will always work as intendend

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumOfElemens; aa = a[i], bb = b[i], ++i) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

I used `i` for increment and `aa` and `bb` to store elements.

Comment: Might want to put an assert (release build) that both array sizes are the same, just before the FOR loop

Comment: @user997112 thanks for your advice!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to bypass your `for` loop question to say if you want to know whether two maps contain the same key-value elements you can use [`std::unordered_map::operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp).

```
unordered_map<char, int> a;
unordered_map<char, int> b;

for (char i : A)
{
    a[i]++;
}
for (char i : B)
{
    b[i]++;
}
if (a == b) // this does the right thing
{
    // the frequencies are the same
}
```